# How to write data to file in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

A little while ago, I started learning Kotlin, and I have done its basics, variables, classes, lists, and arrays, etc. but the book I was learning from seemed to miss one important aspect, reading and writing to a file, maybe a function like "fwrite" in C++

So I searched google, and yes, reading and writing bytes were easy enough. However, I being used to C++'s open personality, wanted to make a "kind of" database.

In C++ I would simply make a struct and keep appending it to a file, and then read all the stored objects one by one, by placing "fread" in a for loop or just reading into an array of the struct in one go, as the struct was simply just the bytes allocated to the variables inside it.

However in Kotlin, there is no struct, instead, we use Data Class to group data. I was hoping there was an equally easy way to store data in a file in form of Data Class and read it into maybe a List of that class, or if that is not possible, maybe some other way to store grouped data that would be easy to read and write.

Comment: Kotlin/JVM or Kotlin/Native?

Comment: It is possible Through ROOM Database

Comment: If you only need to store the data and load it later, then look for **data serialization**. There are many serialization frameworks and many formats. You can serialize your objects into human-readable JSON or into optimized, binary formats like e.g. protobuf. You can do both JSON and protobuf using `kotlinx.serialization` framework form the authors of the Kotlin itself. If you need a way to search through stored data, manipulate it, etc., then you need an embedded database. You can use e.g. sqlite.

Comment: @KartikAgarwal Not everyone is writing for Android…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is to use a serialization library. Kotlin [already provides something for that](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/serialization.html)

TL;DR;

Add [KotlinX Serialization](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization) to your project, choose the serialization format you prefer (protobuf or cbor will fit, go for json if you prefer something more human readable although bigger in size), use the proper serializer for generating your `ByteArray` and write it to a file [using Kotlin methods for that](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/write-bytes.html)

Generating the `ByteArray` might be tricky, not sure as I'm telling this from memory. What I can tell for sure is that if you choose JSON you can get the string representation and write to a file. So I'm assuming the same will be valid for binary formats (but writing to a file in binary instead of strings)

Comment: Ahh i see, looking at the documentation it looks good, however i don't understand how do i import this library into my project? it is an intellij project, with build system set to "IntelliJ", i am also confused about what "Gradle" and "Maven" are...

Comment: Can't really tell how to do it for IntelliJ based build system. For both Gradle and Maven you can find docs in the kotlinx serialization github project. A build system in the end is a piece of software that handles the compilation, testing and rest of building steps of your project. Personally, I recommend Gradle but you could use Maven as well

Comment: yeah i've just switched over to gradle because of that and it worked, so thank you very much!

Comment: Glad it worked :) Consider marking the answer as correct so other people with the same doubts are headed towards proper directions

Answer (score 0):

What you need can be fulfilled by `ROOM DATABASE`

It is officially recommended by GOOGLE, It uses your Android application's internal Database which is made using SQLITE

You can read more info about `ROOM` at

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room?gclid=Cj0KCQjw5ZSWBhCVARIsALERCvwjmJqiRPAnSYjhOzhPXg8dJEYnqKVgcRxSmHRKoyCpnWAPQIWD4gAaAlBnEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds

It provided Data Object Class (DAO) and Entity Classes through which one can access the database TABLE using SQL Queries.

Also, it will check your queries at compile time for any errors in it.

**Note: You need to have basic SQL Knowledge for building the queries for CRUD Operations**

Comment: Is it possible to use Room outside of Android? OP didn't say anything about Android.

Comment: Kotlin is used to create web apps, web services, microservices, stand-alone programs, desktop apps (for a variety of platforms), Android apps, iOS apps, and lots more. The JVM and Android are probably the most common targets, but it's probably helpful if answers don't assume a specific platform — especially if the question doesn't specify one.